# Getting high price and low price from dataframe with the date range(i.e within the week) and then getting date on which high and low made

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC9Sl.png)

I have a dataframe with daily High and low. I want to get maximum of high and minimum of low with the weekstart and weekend. After that I want to plot Date of that max High and Date of minimum low.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import csv
import calendar

fname = '^NSEI'
path_out = 'D:/project/Yahoo Historical data/'
df = yf.download(fname,period="max")
df = df.drop(['Adj Close'], axis=1)
df = df.drop(['Open'], axis=1)
df = df.drop(['Close'], axis=1)
df = df.drop(['Volume'], axis=1)


df['D_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['WkStart'] =df['D_date'].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda r: r.start_time)+ timedelta(days=-1)
df['Wkend'] =df['D_date'].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda r: r.end_time)+ timedelta(days=-1)


print(df)
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Comment: Its in the image

Comment: Image just shows dataframe, we would like to see what approach you tried before posting the problem on SO. Also it's always advised to share sample data instead of image as it helps us to recreate scenarios quickly.

Comment: This is what I have run.